# Show and Read instance for a datatype with functions

Tags: function, parsing, haskell, types

I have a datatype which includes a function value and I want to be able to `show` and `read` it. I know that I can't read the function back, so I want a way to specify the function on reading.

Here is my datatype:

```
  type Activation = (Vector Double -> Vector Double, Vector Double -> Vector Double)

  data Layer = L { biases     :: !(Vector Double)
                 , nodes      :: !(Matrix Double)
                 , activation :: Activation
                 }

  instance Show Layer where
    show (L biases nodes _) = "(" ++ show biases ++ "," ++ show nodes ++ ")"
```

And I want a function like this:

```
readLayer :: String -> Activation -> Layer
```

How would that work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you ignore it when shoiwng, so what do you want to fill the function value with when reading?

Comment: Usually I would use a `String -> String -> Activation -> Layer` function to do that. But what have you tried, what errors are you receiving? Can you build a simple function that "reads" a `String` and creates a `[Double]`, then you might find `Vector.fromList` useful.

Comment: note that this `readLayer` is different from the usual `Read` instance!

Comment: I think this question really just boils down to 'how can I define a `Read` instance by hand?'. Once you know that I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: @PaulVisschers I don't think so `read :: String -> Layer` which is not that simple (you would need something non trivial to parse the activation function)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Well he wouldn't actually make an instance of `Read`, but knowing how to do it would allow him to then make `readLayer` pretty easily.

Comment: @PaulVisschers @epsilonhalbe: I actually wanted to know if this is at all possible with a `Read` instance, but it seems not.

Comment: @MahdiDibaiee Not if you want to provide a function when reading, because the type of such a function is necessarily different from the `read`  function.

Comment: @PaulVisschers Yes, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way you chosen to show a Layer you can just do this:

```
readLayer str f =
  let (biases, nodes) = read str
  in Layer { biases = biases, nodes = nodes, activation = f }
```

That is, your show instance for a Layer is the same as the show instance for (Vector Double, Matrix Double).

Things would get more complicated if that weren't the case.

Comment: or if you are using the LANGUAGE pragma `{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}`, you can write    `readLayer str activation = let (biases, nodes) = read str in Layer{..}`

Comment: I think it's better to be stricter here. While defining such a partial function for parsing input is always problematic, it's generally best to at least make it fail early.

Comment: @dfeuer is this a comment towards my remark or a general one, I don't see in which way my solution is less strict than the original one. Wouldn't the strictness annotation in the type evaluate biases/nodes automatically?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, you're absolutely right. I missed those annotations.